# iOS Keyboard extension: Not showing if no full access

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios8-extension

I am working on an iOS keyboard extension with a containing app. My problem is that I can not "start" the keyboard will not show up. The frame is empty, I can't get into my code. Why is that?
My setup is a quite standard keyboard extension with nothing fancy. I have a hosting application that shows some settings. I store this setting in a NSUserDefaults suite with my app group as the identifier. Do I need full access to access this suite?

Bests,
Philip

UPDATE:

To see if it crashes or exits in the line where I open the settingsSuite I added an NSLog(@"Hello") to the first line of viewDidLoad. It is never reached. I get the following error message:

```
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[16389] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/6A7DF264-59B2-4F38-92CB-63875B6C1469 (sandbox)
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 Fancy Keyboard[16389] <Error>: assertion failed: 12A405: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [4BC9CA3D-4DEE-314C-ADBF-53BDCEEFE45C]: 0x7d
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 Unknown[16389] <Error>: 
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system) <Error>: Caller not allowed to perform action: Fancy Keyboar.16389, action = pid-local registration, code = 1: Operation not permitted, uid = 501, euid = 501, gid = 501, egid = 501, asid = 0
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 Fancy Keyboard[16389] <Error>: _GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace Couldn't register com.apple.accessibility.gax.client with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code (1100).
     This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
Sep 29 12:02:16 iPhone-6 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system) <Error>: Caller not allowed to perform action: Fancy Keyboar.16389, action = pid-local registration, code = 1: Operation not permitted, uid = 501, euid = 501, gid = 501, egid = 501, asid = 0
Sep 29 12:02:17 iPhone-6 ReportCrash[16390] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
```

Any ideas what that means?

Comment: Having an identical issue. It happens about 1 in 10 times I launch the keyboard. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No not at all. I had contact with an Apple engineer about this but in the end it fixed itself with a new iOS version